# How to configure ESLint so that it disallows default exports

Tags: javascript, eslint

I've been searching the web and StackOverflow for this for quite some time with no success.

What I'm trying to do have ESLint mark the following as errors:

```
export default ...;
```

with `default` being the key here. So far the best I've got is a reference to [`eslint-plugin-import`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import) plugin and some of its rules that can make me closer to the target, namely the [no-anonymous-default-export](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md) rule. But even with this rule the following default exports would be valid:

```
const foo = 123
export default foo

export default class MyClass() {}

export default function foo() {}
```

How can I configure ESLint in such a way that these four would also be considered errors?

Comment: There are no such rules. Actually we have [the opposite](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-default-export.md) where if you have only one exported symbol it should be default.

Comment: @Sylwester that was exactly the impression I got, yet this is not ideal for our codebase

Comment: @Dethariel Can you clarify the specific issue you are facing with default exports in your codebase? I cannot think of a reason why they should be problematic at all, and I'd like to help you avoid an XY problem.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan the only problem is consistency. We want to settle down with `import { Foo } from 'foo';` kinda thing versus `import Bar from 'bar';` for the reasons of our team preference, and having a linting rule to check for such things would have been great

Comment: @Dethariel I suppose that makes sense. You can always [define your own rule](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/27/writing-custom-eslint-rules/) or alternatively propose it to ESLint.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're already using `eslint-plugin-import`, you can use the [`no-default-export`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-default-export.md) rule (which was added around February 2018).

Answer (score 20):

You can do this with the [`no-restricted-syntax` rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax). Try pasting this in the [demo](http://eslint.org/demo) to try it out (you'll need to change "Source Type" to "module" first in the options):

```
/* eslint "no-restricted-syntax": ["error", {
    "selector": "ExportDefaultDeclaration",
    "message": "Prefer named exports"
  }] */
export default class Foo { } // 5:1 - Prefer named exports (no-restricted-syntax)
```

Answer (score 9):

As it's already answered in accepted answer, worth mentioning when working in Next.js projects, I like to do:

```
'import/no-default-export': 'error',
overrides: [
  // Pages router
  {
    files: ['src/pages/**/*'],
    rules: {
      'import/no-default-export': 'off',
    },
  },
  // App router
  {
    files: ['src/app/**/{page,layout,not-found}.tsx'],
    rules: {
      'import/no-default-export': 'off',
    },
  },
],
```

Where the only exception is routed pages, which must be default exported in Next.js.

Comment: for app router `["src/app/**/page.tsx"]`